# Operações com vetor de Bytes em C#

Tags: c#, array, criptografia

Sou novo em programação e estou trabalhando em um algoritmo de criptografia RSA.
Os processos de geração de chaves, cálculos estão quase prontos...  Tenho um vetor de bytes que recebe a mensagem digitada pelo usuário utilizando o `GetBytes()`, mas preciso de uma forma pra efetuar cálculos com os bytes armazenados em cada posição do vetor, podendo então criptografar e descriptografar com as fórmulas matemáticas que tenho sendo:

> "C" a mensagem criptografada, "M" a mensagem digitada codificada em ASCII e "E", "N"

Minhas chaves de valores numéricos, obtendo a fórmula **C = M^E mod (N).** Não estou conseguindo fazer cálculos com os bytes, alguma ideia de como fazer isso? segue um trecho do código:

```
   Console.WriteLine("\nDigite um texto para codificar: ");
   string str = Console.ReadLine();
   Codes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: Apresente os calculos que está fazendo e como está implementando a formula.

Comment: O que é o **E** e o **N** na sua fórmula?